# How to style email body in php

Tags: php, html, css, email

I want to style mail body. I have tried the below methods to style mail body. But all of them didn't work

1) Used external style sheet 
 **style.css**

```
td{padding:10px;}
```

**mail.php**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></link><table><td>....</td></table>
```

2) Defined Internal Style Sheet:

**mail.php**

```
 <style type="text/css">
td{
    padding-bottom:8px;
}

</style>
<table><td>....</td></table>
```

I know, Inline style works by doing `<td style='padding-bottom:8px'>`, But i have got many tables, doing the inline style is not a good idea, Is there any work around so that no need to define style for each element

Comment: Email clients are very, very picky about what CSS stuff they will and will not render.  Your best bet is to find a comprehensive guide on email styling (wish I could think of a link off the top of my head but I can't).

Comment: I couldn't find one.  I found that stand-alone email clients are paranoid about security but will at least render most HTML.  The crazy stuff is when you try to support the free providers.  Gmail strips background images but leaves colours.  Hotmail turns all background colours grey.  Yahoo does something else.  Makes me want to send a plaintext email that just says "copy this URL to your browser."

Comment: older versions of outlook will ignore most css, and modern css positining..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for email, usually the safest bet is tables and inline styles (Everything you shouldn't be doing in web design).

```
$mailBody = '<html><body>';
$mailBody .='<table width="100%"><tr>';
$mailBody .='<td style="padding:10px"></td>';
$mailBody .='<td style="padding:10px"></td>';
$mailBody .='<td style="padding:10px"></td>';
$mailBody .='</tr></table>';
$mailBody .='</body></html>';
```

Sadly internal and external style sheets don't always work across different email clients.

Answer (score 2):

Typically tables are the way to go. Unfortunately to get the most widespread support you need to use inline styles. A lot do cascade so you don't have to style every element however. For example using `font-family` on a `table` element would apply it to `td` elements.

Campaign monitor provides a useful overview of support for CSS across the most common email clients here http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Email boilerplate ( http://htmlemailboilerplate.com/ ) will also provide you with a template with which you can start and it'll teach you how to avoid a lot of the common shortcommings of many email clients.

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution. Please check this out: [CSS to Inline style](http://classes.verkoyen.eu/css_to_inline_styles)

There is also another library that does the same task. http://www.pelagodesign.com/sidecar/emogrifier/

Basically these libraries convert your css style rules into inline styles, so that all the email clients will render your HTML document correctly