# How to bold PHP output in mail()?

Tags: php, email

I have this line of PHP code here...

```
$lang['message_form_5'] ='Would '.$_POST["firstname"].' like to be considered for a Committee role? '.$finaltoggle_checkbox_2.'';
```

I'm trying to bold it on output to an email, which is sent to the Admin for the site.

I have tried this...

```
$lang['message_form_5'] ='Would "<strong>"'.$_POST["firstname"].'"</strong>" like to be considered for a Committee role? "<strong>"'.$finaltoggle_checkbox_2.'"</strong>"';
```

...and this...

```
$lang['message_form_5'] ='Would '.$_POST[<b>"firstname"</b>].' like to be considered for a Committee role? <b>'.$finaltoggle_checkbox_2.'</b>';
```

...but neither is working...

Thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to style email body in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883719/how-to-style-email-body-in-php)

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the entire output in <html></html>?

Comment: I don't want the entire output in a wrapper... just certain parts. Like the question in bold, but the answer is not in bold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the mail is sending as html  not  Text

If the mail type is html `<b>` will work.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

For PHPMAILER

Before sending this out, we have to modify the PHPMailer object to indicate that the message should be interpreted as HTML. Technically-speaking, the message body has to be set up as multipart/alternative. This is done with:

```
$mail->IsHTML(true);
```

http://phpmailer.worxware.com/?pg=tutorial

http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23737696-How-do-I-send-with-PHPMailer-

Comment: I'm using PHPmailer, so no headers are required. `<b>` didn't work, but `<strong>` does work.